# Run one of two for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

Suppose I had 2 for loops, each contains an if and else statement, I want it to work so that if the first `for`loop is achieved then to break and not run the second for loop. Probably a very simple solution, thanks any help.

The aim of this program is to read a user input and iterate over the `int` given, if the user doesn't input a int value then to iterate over 100.

As this code is everything is working except it is doing both loops, I want it to do one or the other.

```
package coreprog;
   ...

       for (...){
         ...
         if (...) {
           ...
          }
       else
         System.out.println(...);
      }  


      for (...){
         ...
         if (...) {
           ...
          }
       else
         System.out.println(...);
```

Comment: Do these loops contain the exact same logic but only differ in the number of loops based on user input or lack there of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a Boolean flag inside first for loop  and Make it true before break.Based on it  do it whatever you want to do. For example :-

```
boolean firstConditionAchieved= false;

 for (...){
         ...
         if (...) {
           firstConditionAchieved = true;
           ...
          }
       else
         System.out.println(...);
      }
```

**Second loop :-**

```
if(!firstConditionAchieved){
......


}
```

Comment: You have a typo: `fallse`

Comment: just a note for anyone with this issue. This answer is correct however depending on your second `if` you may not be able to do `if(!firstConditionAchieved){` as suggested. Instead create a `while` loop before the second `for` loop as follows: `while (firstConditionAchieved){`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of boolean variable and check the boolean variable in if condition. If the variable is set skips out of the loop and doesn't execute the second loop and do the vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read an `int` value and iterate over it, or over 100 if not supplied, you only need one loop.

```
read N
if not read or not valid N then N = 100
for i = 1 to N do
    ...
```